# What is the result of Oracle TO_NCHAR?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM DUAL WHERE TO_CHAR('666a') = 666
```

ORA-01722: INVALID NUMBER

---

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM DUAL WHERE TO_NCHAR('666a') = '666'
```

RESULT: 0

---

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM DUAL WHERE TO_NCHAR('666a') = '666a'
```

RESULT: 1

---

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM DUAL WHERE TO_NCHAR('666a') = 666
```

RESULT: 1

---

**WHY** the last SQL result is 1?

**WHY** the result of TO_NCHAR could be compared with a number?

And it occurs in Oracle 11.2.0.3, but trigger ORA-01722 in Oracle 11.2.0.4

Comment: Try `TO_NUMBER(TO_NCHAR('666a'))`, it returns 666. However, I don't know why Oracle behaves like that in contradiction to `TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR('666a'))`

Comment: also you can use chars after numbers to max length of numbers I mean you can use `TO_NCHAR('666abs')`because 666 s length is 3 so you can use max 3 chars, if you use 4 chars it gives error, And you want to use more chars so you should have more numbers I mean `TO_NCHAR('6589ahjk')`it works again but I do not know why

Comment: I've replaced the "plsql" tag with "sql". PL/SQL is the procedural language with BEGIN, END, IF, THEN, variables etc. This is pure SQL.

Comment: Seems to me like it's a bug in 11.2.0.3. A bug that was corrected in 11.2.0.4. Based on the datatype comparison rules and datatype precedence, we'd expect the behavior observed in 11.2.0.4 (the ORA-1722 error.)